# Getting the name of the current method in c++

Tags: c++, introspection

Is there a (standardized) way to get the name of the current method using c++?

Using GNU GCC you can do this by using the macro `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` (surrounded by 2 underscores), however, this is of course non portable. Is there a way to do this in standard c++ or a way to make it portable?

Comment: you can escape the underscores using backslashes to prevent markdown messing them up...

Comment: Or by clicking the "code" button in the editor, which is what I did when I edited it.

Comment: I use [`BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/utility/current_function.html)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `__func__` identifier is part of the C99 standard and is in the C++0x draft.

The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the compiler as if the following were at the very start of each function body:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

where `function-name` is an implementation-defined string automatically provided by the compiler.

Until support for those standards is available (or more widely available) you're stuck with compiler-specific gunk.

Answer (score 1):

No...... but some things end up being non standard standards!

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx   which outlines the ANSI standard stuff, and then microsofs   which includes *FUNCTION*

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported by c++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "introspection" and there is no such a thing in c++ standards. You should use an external library (boost I think supports it somehow).
But try figure out if the reason for using it is really a good one.